# How to execute command to list today's updated files using batch file

Tags: batch-file

Need to write batch file to perform below command(TO LIST FILE DETAILS UPDATED TODAY):

```
D:\RMAN_BACKUP\BACKUP>FORFILES /D +12/12/2016 /C "cmd /c echo @fname is new today"

"test" is new today
"test.txt" is new today
```

I have write below code to create string of command but not able to execute it through batch file:(.

```
cd D:/RMAN_BACKUP/BACKUP/
echo off
set str1=FORFILES /D 
set str2=+%date:~4,2%/%date:~7,2%/%date:~10,4% 
set str3=/C "cmd /c echo @fname is new today
set strnew=%str1% %str2% %str3%"
set strfi=echo.%strnew%
%strfi%
cmd.exe
```

New approach with new command would be appropriate,Just trying.

Below is output I am receiving while executing above code in batch file:

```
C:\Users\SM\Desktop>d:

D:\>cd D:/RMAN_BACKUP/BACKUP/

D:\RMAN_BACKUP\BACKUP>echo off
FORFILES /D  +12/12/2016  /C "cmd /c echo @fname is new today"
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

Thanks,
SM

Comment: This is incredibly convoluted. But anyway, you're missing a closing quote at str3.

Comment: I am ok with code but using this code you will get string.My question is how to execute that final string using batch file.If you execute this code at the end you will get string like below how to execute it?                                 FORFILES  /D +12/12/2016 /C "cmd /c echo @fname is new today

Comment: How about now ?I have edited command.

Comment: `forfiles /d +0`. So `cmd /k forfiles /d +0`. See `cmd /?`. You code is obfuscated. Code should be simple.

Comment: Why the `cmd.exe` at the end? A way to see what the problem is is just to echo the `%strfi%` instead of executing it. On my system the error comes from the `str2`: you're using the wrong indices to select the day, month and year from your date-variable. Keep in mind that indices while extracting substring are 0 based (first character has index 0, not 1). But as the date-variable may depend on the language settings I don't know if this is the problem on your system. As I said, `echo %strfi%` will reveal a lot

Comment: The `/D +0` option of `forfiles` is sufficient to get all items that have been modified today, because `forfiles` does not care about the time at all, but the pure date only...

Comment: See `cmd /?`. You are starting a new interactive shell at the end.